# Laravel query builder issue join table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I make filtering data using laravel we have member and date range, my problem is cannot read the `members.name` column:

```php
$query->whereBetween('excels.created_at', [$from_date, $to_date])
->where('members.name', "LIKE", "%" . $member . "%");
```

This is my error, my joining table is correct but when I filtering the data they have error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfOil.png)

Comment: what is $query???

Comment: that means members does not exists in that collection. cant you post dump of given collection.

Comment: Your question requires more details. Make sure you're querying the right model.  What's the relationship between members and excels table/model? What's the initial $query?

Comment: can you send member relation on your model.

Comment: @gerl this is my query from my controller `   $excel = ExcelModel::join('members', 'members.id', '=', 'excels.member_id')
            ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($search) {
               
            })
            ->dateFilter($member, $from_date, $to_date)
            ->take($request->length)
            ->skip($request->start)
            ->get(['excels.*', 'members.name as MemberName']);`

Comment: the **dateFilter** is function of my model.
 public function scopeDateFilter($query, $member = null, $from_date = null, $to_date = null)
    {
        if (!empty($from_date)) {
            $from_date = date('Y-m-d 00:00:01', strtotime($from_date));

            $to_date = (!empty($to_date)) ? date('Y-m-d 23:59:59', strtotime($to_date)) : date('Y-m-d 23:59:59');

            $query->whereBetween('excels.created_at', [$from_date, $to_date])->where('excels.LoginId', "LIKE", "%" . $member . "%");
        }

        return $query;
    }

Comment: can you add these in your question?